# Test Excel "Date System" before run line code

Tags: excel, vba

I am from Brazil and here date is expressed as dd/mm/yyyy. So, what VBA command should I use so that I can have guaranteed that the following MsgBox will return "01" and not "02"?

```
MyDate ="02/01/2001"
MsgBox Month(MyDate) 'I want 01 as month
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
If Excel.DateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" then MyMonth = Month(MyDate)
```

Is that possible? What VBA command guarantees me that excel reads "02/01/2001" as "dd/mm/yyyy" and not as "mm/dd/yyyy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If Application.International(xlDateOrder) = 0 Then ...
```

xlDateOrder has the following choices:

```
0 = month-day-year
1 = day-month-year
2 = year-month-day
```

More info here: 
[Application.International](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-international-property-excel)

Comment: I dont know which is the amazing-est: excel object model or stackoverflow members :)